# How to create wordpress password hash generator using php?

Tags: php, wordpress, hash, passwords, php-password-hash

I want to create WordPress password hash using PHP like www.passwordtool.hu.

An example:

*Password*: admin321

*Wordpress Password Hash*: $1$8HmCMIeg$qv9z585yftJa2Hxqo7/RB/

For testing purpose here is the tool **Online Password Generator Tool**:  http://www.passwordtool.hu/wordpress-password-hash-generator-v3-v4

How to create this WordPress password using wordpress default functions?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Wordpress provides a default function [wp_hash_password();](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_hash_password/)

Example:

```
$password = 'admin';
$hash_password = wp_hash_password($password);
echo $hash_password;
```

To work this in PHP just load `wp-load.php`, So that you can use default wordpress functions.

Wordpress actually use [Portable PHP password hashing framework](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/). WP has this included in `/wp-includes/class-phpass.php`

Comment: Thank You Very Much. I create a WordPress password hash generator tool using this function.  Link: https://www.webcods.com/tools/wordpress-password-hash-generator.php

Comment: Thats great @Muyin :-)

Comment: This answer is so great, for an off-topic question, this question and answer was pretty much what I needed. I don't care, voting this answer and question up! I could wrap up a commandline to quickly hash these provided I have PHP commandline tool and a wordpress copy handy:
`php -r 'include("wp-load.php"); print("Password: ".wp_hash_password("my_passowd")."\n");'`